# Curvature Scale Space corner detection algorithm. Arc Length Parameter?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, opencv, feature-detection

I'm studying about the CSS algorithm and I don't get the hang of the concept of 'Arc Length Parameter'.

According to the literature, planar curve Gamma(u)=(x(u),y(u)) and they say this u is the arc length parameter and apparently, Gaussian Kernel g is also parameterized by this u here.

Stop me if I got something wrong but, aren't x and y location of the pixel? How is it represented by another parameter?

I had no idea when I first saw it on the literature so, I looked up the code. and apparently, I got puzzled even more.

here is the portion of the code

```
    void getGaussianDerivs(double sigma, int M, vector<double>& gaussian,                       
                           vector<double>& dg, vector<double>& d2g) {
        int L = (M - 1) / 2;
        double sigma_sq = sigma * sigma;
        double sigma_quad = sigma_sq*sigma_sq;
        dg.resize(M); d2g.resize(M); gaussian.resize(M);

        Mat_<double> g = getGaussianKernel(M, sigma, CV_64F);
        for (double i = -L; i < L+1.0; i += 1.0) {
        int idx = (int)(i+L);
        gaussian[idx] = g(idx);
            // from http://www.cedar.buffalo.edu/~srihari/CSE555/Normal2.pdf
        dg[idx] = (-i/sigma_sq) * g(idx);
        d2g[idx] = (-sigma_sq + i*i)/sigma_quad * g(idx);
        }
    }
```

so, it seems the code uses simple 1D Gaussian Kernel Aperture size of M and it is trying to compute its 1st and 2nd derivatives. As far as I know, 1D Gaussian kernel has parameter of x which is a horizontal coordinate and sigma which is scale. it seems like that 'arc length parameter u' is equivalent to the variable of x. That doesn't make any sense because later in the code, it directly convolutes the set of x and y on the contour.

what is this u?

PS. since I replied to the fellow who tried to answer my question, I think I should modify my question, so, here we go.

What I'm confusing is, how is this parameter 'u' implemented in codes? I think I understood the full code above -of course, I inserted only a portion of the code- but the problem is, I have no idea about what it would be for the 'improved' version of the algorithm. It says it's using 'affine length parameter' instead of this 'arc length parameter' and I'm not so sure how I implement the concept into the code.

According to the literature, the main difference between arc length parameter and affine length parameter is it's sampling interval and arc length parameter uses 1 for the vertical and horizontal direction and root of 2 for the diagonal direction. It makes sense since the portion of the code above is using for loop to compute 1st and 2nd derivatives of the 1d Gaussian and it directly inserts the value of interval 1 but, how is it gonna be with different interval with different variable? Is it possible that I'm not able to use 'for loop' for it?

Comment: Are you asking why the coordinates x and y of each point on a planar curve can be expressed as two functions of a common parameter u, x = fun_one(u) and y = fun_two(u)? That follows pretty much from the definition of a planar curve.

Comment: What I'm confusing is, how is it implemented in codes? I think I understood the full code above -of course, I inserted only a portion of the code- but the problem is, I have no idea about what it would be for the 'improved' version of the algorithm. It says it's using 'affine length prameter' instead of this 'arc length parameter' and I'm not so sure how I implement the concept into the code.

Comment: According to the literature, the main difference between arc length parameter and affine length parameter is it's interval and arc length parameter uses 1 for the vertical and horizontal direction and root of 2 for the diagonal direction. It makes sense since the portion of the code above is using for loop to compute 1st and 2nd derivatives of the 1d Gaussian and it directly inserts the value of interval 1 but, how is it gonna be with different interval with different variable? Is it possible that I'm not able to use 'for loop' for it?